# Run Java app from Java with space in .jar file path

Tags: java

I'm trying to run Java CUP (Java version for LEX/YACC parser) from within a Java application.

This is the code I have (I copied most of it from the internet):

```
String command  = "java " +
                  "-jar " +
                  "\"g:My Documents\\Dropbox\\Final Project\\Code\\Mano CPU\\Inputs\\Parser\\java-cup-11a.jar\" " +
                  "-destdir " +
                  "\"g:\\My Documents\\Dropbox\\Final Project\\Code\\Mano CPU\\src\\Assembler\" " +
                  "\"G:\\My Documents\\Dropbox\\Final Project\\Code\\Mano CPU\\Inputs\\Assembler\\Assembler.cup\"";

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line=reader.readLine();
while(line!=null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
    line=reader.readLine();
}
```

When I run this command in the command prompt of Win 7 (Without escaping the back-slashes and double-quoutes), it gets executed. If I comment out everything after "-jar", I get the java options (Which is expected, as the command is illegal), so I know it can run.

My guess is that passing a path with spaces is the problem. I tried using String[], but I get the same results. Escaping the spaces causes an error as well.

Does anybody have any idea as to how I can solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You're missing a backslash (`g:My Documents`).  I don't have Windows handy to test whether that's legal, but I don't think it is.

Comment: I'm not sure it's necessary to include escaped quotes when using `Runtime.exec()` since it doesn't go through a shell.)

Comment: @millimoose ah! Thanks, I didn't know that.  In fact, [Runtime#exec(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String\)) apparently just uses a StringTokenizer to split the command string, so OP is going to need to use [Runtime#exec(String[\])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[]\)) instead.

Comment: 1. As to the missing back-slash, it got deleted in one of the many changes I made. Fixing it didn't do anything.
2. Without the escaped quotes I get a 'null' exception.
3. There's no change when switching from one string to a string array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the first backslash in the path to your jar:

```
String command  = "java " +
                  "-jar " +
                  "\"g:My Documents\\Dropbox\\Final Project\\Code\\Mano CPU\\Inputs\\Parser\\java-cup-11a.jar\" " +
```

should be

```
String command  = "java " +
                  "-jar " +
                  "\"g:\\My Documents\\Dropbox\\Final Project\\Code\\Mano CPU\\Inputs\\Parser\\java-cup-11a.jar\" " +
                       ^^
```

---

**Edit:** millimoose pointed out that [`Runtime#exec(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't use the shell to invoke, so I checked the documentation and it apparently just uses a [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to *split on spaces*.  Java is gonna split your command arguments even though they're wrapped in double-quotes.  So in addition to fixing the backslash issue above, you're going to need to use the form of [`exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) which accepts a `String[]`.  And you won't need to double-quote arguments containing spaces.

```
String[] command = new String[] {
                       "java",
                       "-jar",
                       "g:\\My Documents\\Dropbox\\Final Project\\Code\\Mano CPU\\Inputs\\Parser\\java-cup-11a.jar",
                       "-destdir",
                       "g:\\My Documents\\Dropbox\\Final Project\\Code\\Mano CPU\\src\\Assembler",
                       "G:\\My Documents\\Dropbox\\Final Project\\Code\\Mano CPU\\Inputs\\Assembler\\Assembler.cup",
                   };

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: The back-slash in the first argument got deleted by accident with all the copy-pasting. Adding it doesn't solve the problem.
using a String array doesn't solve it either (As mentioned in the original post).
When using an array with one string only, I get an error that says the file specified can't be found, which is much better than previous attempts.

Comment: Ok.  Could you post the stacktrace for the error you get then?

Comment: Apparently I had no output, but the files I needed were created nonetheless.

Comment: Ah, weird.  Glad it's working now.  Maybe the process output something on the error stream?

Comment: It's a CUP compilation, I believe it outputs on the stdoud stream. I'll check stderr.

Comment: I just checked the CUP source code, and it seems to output nearly everything to stderr.  Seems kind of unusual, but at least it's mostly consistent...

Comment: Indeed, I just changed `p.getInputStream()` to `p.getErrorStream()` and I get the expected output.